# How to add function to display custom placeholder anywhere on html?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

So i will try to explain what i need to do so i have a plugin for listing places on a map and it shows markers from custom fields. And you can style the listing as html also insert some shortcodes like {post_title}, {post_tags} etc and it displays the fields from the custom post type. So i need to create a placeholder for a php function to add a funcionality for Add to wishlist im using favorites plugin and it has the function: the_favorites_button($post_id, $site_id); but its not working to add the funcionality to all posts.

When im adding the function the_favorites_button($post_id, $site_id); to this if it shows the icons but not where i need on a listing. It shows all buttons before the listing.

```
if ( $wpgmp_the_query->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $wpgmp_the_query->have_posts() ) {
                    $wpgmp_the_query->the_post();
                    the_favorites_button($post_id, $site_id);
                    global $post;
                    $places         = array();
                    $content        = $infowindow_post_view_source;
                    $category_names = '';
                    if ( isset( $value['acf_key'] ) ) {
                        $acf_key        = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $value['acf_key'], true );
                    } else {
                        $acf_key = array();
                    }

                    if ( empty( $acf_key['lat'] ) && empty( $acf_key['lng'] ) ) {

                        if ( empty( $value['latitude'] ) or empty( $value['longitude'] ) ) {
                            continue; }
                            // Check if meta post is assigned to $map->map_id.
                        if ( '_wpgmp_location_address' == $value['address'] ) {

                            $wpgmp_map_ids = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wpgmp_map_id', true );
                            $wpgmp_map_id  = unserialize( $wpgmp_map_ids );

                            if ( ! is_array( $wpgmp_map_id ) ) {
                                        $wpgmp_map_id = array( $wpgmp_map_ids );
                            }
                            if ( ! in_array( $map->map_id, $wpgmp_map_id ) ) {
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $replace_data['post_title']   = get_the_title();`
```

Output:

```html
<div class="fc-item-box fc-component-2  wpgmp_locations col-md-3">
    <div class="fc-component-block">
        <div class="fc-component-content">
                <div class="fc-item-featured fc-component-thumb fc-item-top_space">
                    <div class="fc-featured-hoverdiv">
                        <div class="fc-featured-hoverinner "><a {onclick_action}="" class="map"></a></div>
                        {marker_image}
                </div>

                <div class="fc-component-text">
                    <div class="fc-itemcontent-padding">                     
 <img id="markeris" src="https://keliauklietuvoje.lt/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/Vector.png"> <p id="addressi">{%adresas%}</p>
<div class="fc-bookmark-info">
{is_favorite}
</div>
                      <div class="fc-item-title fc-item-primary-text-color ">{marker_title}</div>
                        <div class="fc-item-content fc-item-body-text-color">
                            {marker_message}
  <a href="{post_link}">LEARN MORE</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like the actual output of your posts is happening in that snippet you have shown us.

Comment: `get_post_meta()` unserializes if necessary, for what it's worth.

Comment: I need {is_favorite} to add the Add to wishlist button there, but its not working not getting the post.